# CodeIgniter 3, Nginx rewrite how to?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, url-rewriting

I installed CodeIgniter 3 after a long time on PHP-fpm and nginx (Ubuntu). Previously I had always used CodeIgniter on Windows and configuring it on Windows and Apache it was a piece of cake.
Now I wanna install it on nginx, because I wanna use nginx-push-stream-module, which isn't possible from apache.

Now when I'm configuring it, its not working.

If I type `localhost/myexample.com` or `localhost/myexample.com/index.php` it works (`myexample.com` is the name of that directory)

but when I try to access

```
localhost/myexample.com/welcome
```

or

```
localhost/myexample.com/welcome/index
```

or

```
localhost/myexample.com/index.php/welcome
```

or

```
localhost/myexample.com/index.php/welcome/index
```

it doesn't work in any of the 4 cases (with or without index.php)

My root directory is `/var/www/html/myexample.com`

I tried all of the rewrite settings available online (including the following settings) from different blog posts etc (as I'm not used to nginx myself)

```
server {
    server_name myexample.com;
    root /var/www/html/myexample.com/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        expires           15d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/myexample.com/index.php;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI      $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     }
}
```

**Edit: I also tried [the method](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/) mentioned at Nginx's official website, but that's also not working.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your /etc/hosts and add this line:

> 127.0.0.1 myexample.com

And after that use *myexample.com* or *myexample.com/welcome* to access your CodeIgniter site

Answer (score 0):

First - confirm what the server name is going to be. Set that in the your hosts file, then confirm the web root.

So in /etc/hosts add

```
127.0.0.1 myexample.com
```

Then your index.php file should be in

```
/var/www/html/myexample.com/
```

You should get CI up and working on the url

```
http://myexample.com
```